# Creating a slide in animation with the Angular ng-content element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-animations

I'm trying to create a component that will slide in content projected with `ng-content` ([This is the Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tsw7a6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)).

This is the animation.

```
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  transition,
  animate,
  group,
} from '@angular/animations';

export const SlideInOutAnimation = [
  trigger('slideInOut', [
    state(
      'in',
      style({
        height: '100%',
        opacity: '1',
        visibility: 'visible',
      })
    ),
    state(
      'out',
      style({
        height: '0px',
        opacity: '0',
        visibility: 'hidden',
      })
    ),
    transition('in => out', [
      group([
        animate(
          '400ms ease-in-out',
          style({
            opacity: '0',
          })
        ),
        animate(
          '600ms ease-in-out',
          style({
            'max-height': '0px',
          })
        ),
        animate(
          '700ms ease-in-out',
          style({
            visibility: 'hidden',
          })
        ),
      ]),
    ]),
    transition('out => in', [
      group([
        animate(
          '1ms ease-in-out',
          style({
            visibility: 'visible',
          })
        ),
        animate(
          '600ms ease-in-out',
          style({
            height: '100%',
          })
        ),
        animate(
          '800ms ease-in-out',
          style({
            opacity: '1',
          })
        ),
      ]),
    ]),
  ]),
];
```

And this is the `HelloComponent` refactored to use the animation.

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  SimpleChanges,
  ViewEncapsulation,
} from '@angular/core';
import { SlideInOutAnimation } from './animation';

@Component({
  animations: [SlideInOutAnimation],
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<ng-content [@slideInOut]="animationState"></ng-content>`,
  styles: [
    `hello { position: absolute;
             background: red; 
             height: 0px;
             bottom: 0;
             visibility: hidden;
     }`,
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() animationState: string = 'in';
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes.animationState);
  }
}
```

When the `animationState` is toggled it is logged in the console. However, the projected content does not animate in.

Any ideas?

Comment: <ng-cpntent> is not an element and it can't be usedd like this. instead you could apply animation to the host itself by using @HostBinding('@animationTrigger') and apply animation to its children with the help of `query` api

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Andrei in the comments I use `@HostBinding` instead and now it works.

```
  @HostBinding('@slideInOut')
  get currentAnimationState() {
    return this.animationState;
  }
```

[This is a new Stackblitz with the working demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qs2mfz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)